# Jquery UI Slider, multiple value output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to configure a slider to display multiple values with one being a standard number output and the other being an output from a value in an array.

http://jsfiddle.net/YKBRWC/7B5jK/1/

I would like the values in the handle to be the standard 1-100 but the values underneath to correspond with a custom array that I would define.

In other words, how would I link

```
$("#amount").html(value);
```

to out an array of something like:

```
[1=15,2=23,3=26,4=32,5=39]
```

etc?

Comment: What's the code for the array and where in your fiddle should the values from it be displayed?

Comment: Have you tried using a dictionary? E.g. `{ 1: 15, 2: 23, ... }`

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/EvPTj/5/

```
var ageInput = $("#ageInput"),
    initialValue = 1,
    values = [];

values = ['',15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39,15,23,26,32,39];

var updateSliderValue = function (e, ui) {
    var slider = $(this).data().slider;
    var index = ui.value || 0;
    if (index) {
        $("#amount").html(index + "=" + values[index]);
        slider.element.find(".ui-slider-handle").text(slider.value());
    }
};

var value = $("#slider").slider("value");
$("#amount").html(value);


ageInput.slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: updateSliderValue,
    create: updateSliderValue,
    value: initialValue
});
```

af

Comment: Excellent, just what I need!