# JQuery: Change value when value of other input field is changed with a range of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I was wondering if someone can help me develop this in Jquery (mobile):

I want to make two text fields, in the first one you have to enter a number and in the other one I want to see a result. I mean something like this:

**example 1:**

```
textfield 1: 220 till 285 < input

textfield 2: 1 < result
```

**example 2:**

```
textfield 1: 286 till 350 < input


textfield 2: 2 < result
```

**example 3:**

```
textfield 1: 351 till 415 < input

textfield 2: 3 < result
```

This must happen automatically and not with pressing a button, etc., [like this method](http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/QWSQp/71/)

UpdATE!
What i mean is more a range like this: input: for example the numberrange 220 till 285 will result in 1. 286 till 350 in 2. 351 till 415 in 3. So all the numbers between for example 351 - 415 must has 3 as output

Comment: why don't you use the code from jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the keyUp event provided by jquery:

html

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
<input type="text" id="output" />
```

js

```
$('#input').keyup(function() {
    $('#output').val($('#input').val().substring(0,1));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uGLpt/

EDIT

You can check the input with simple if-conditions:

```
$('#input').keyup(function () {
    var value = $('#input').val();

    if(value >= 220 && value <= 285)
        $('#output').val(1);
    else if(value >= 286 && value <= 350)
        $('#output').val(2);
    else if(value >= 351 && value <= 415)
        $('#output').val(3);
    else
        $('#output').val("");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uGLpt/4/

Comment: how is it different from my answer? stop copying code!

Comment: My answer uses the keyUp event what your answer didn't before your edit (you used the change event, didn't you?)... Thats rather uncool by you...

Comment: so u were tracking my answer! i changed it the instance i double checked the OPs example fiddle

Comment: @AJ I didn't especially tracked you anser... ever heared about browser history? In every case in the moment I posted my answer were different than yours and yours was not the correct solution for the question...

Comment: This i exact what i need!! one last question. is it possible to make two different ranges in one code and switch between them with a checkbox, so i can use the same tekstfields and the user can you choose between the 2 different ranges?

Comment: Of course that is possible. You can add a checkbox and get with `$('#checkbox').prop('checked');` if it is checked. Therewith you can adapt the code in the keyup event of the textbox.

Comment: Okay, i'm trying to invert the checkbox. But i'm just a starter sow that pretty difficult for me. Can you explain me a little bit more how this process works?

Comment: It's harder than i thought to add a checkbox. I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/uGLpt/21/ but its not working.

Comment: The only problem is when i uncheck the checkbox the value does not change to range 1. First i have to re-enter the value before it will change in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akbV9/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#txt1").keyup(function(){
    $("#txt2").val($("#txt1").val()/50);
});
});

<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
```

Comment: @user3341223 : does my answer fix your issue?

Comment: No, i'm sorrie i think i had to be more specific. What i mean is more a range like this: input: for example the numberrange 220 till 285 will result in 1. 286 till 350 in 2. 351 till 415 in 3. So all the numbers between for example 351 - 415 must has 3 as output.

Comment: you need an explanation too? or what should be the logic to set the second textbox. I thought it should show the first character from you example

Comment: The logic from the textboxes is that the first tekstbox were you enter a value (a range of numbers) is a input field in my form. A few pages later in my form i have the second textfield. Both tekstboxes must interact with eachother.

Comment: In the first textbox you enter a value (a number between a big range for example 0-1000). What i want is: connect a number to a range 0-50 = 1 or 50-100 = 2 etc till 1000. value 1 or 2 etc. must be in tekstbox 2. I found something similar. only this guy made it with a slider. Maybe this wil explain more my idea [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078763/jquery-ui-slider-multiple-value-output] . Sorry for my first example, i think it was to simple and not specific enough.